# How to zebra stripe the console?

Tags: command-line, console, terminator

I'd like the terminal to alternate the background color on successive lines, making it easier to see where one starts and the next one ends. This would be specially useful when reading logs with tail -f, but, I'd prefer a solution that works all the time. Specially if it's something I can use with Terminator, though I'd be willing to use a different terminal if it has this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Might need a custom terminal to get this sort of functionality in all circumstances but for things like `tail -f` the following `python3` script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import shutil
import sys

try:
  from termcolor import cprint
except:
  print("Error: please install the python3-termcolor package")
  sys.exit(1)

def expandtabs(line):
  """Tabs don't seem to be highlighted so expand them to spaces"""
  result = ""
  col = 0
  for c in line:
    if c == "\t":
      next_col = 8 * ((col // 8) + 1)
      result += " " * (next_col - col)
      col = next_col
    else:
      result += c
      col += 1
  return result

def pad(line, n):
  """Pad a line until it is a multiple of n, to avoid jagged highlighting"""
  while (len(line) % n) != 0:
    line += " "
  return line

# Get the width of the terminal
cols, rows = shutil.get_terminal_size()

try:
  odd = True
  for line in sys.stdin:
    if odd:
      cprint(pad(expandtabs(line.rstrip()), cols), "white", "on_grey")
    else:
      cprint(pad(expandtabs(line.rstrip()), cols), "grey", "on_white")
    odd = not odd
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  sys.exit(0)
```

If saved as `zebra.py` someplace in your path, it can be added to commands such as:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | zebra.py
tail -f /var/log/kern.log | zebra.py
```

It requires the `python3-termcolor` package and at least Python 3.3 to use the `shutil.get_terminal_size` function. There is plenty of room for improvement, could try the `python3-xtermcolor` package to gain more than just the few colors at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor, add functionality to read files from the command line instead of just `stdin`, etc.

I'm not sure it makes output much easier to read, but it certainly looks neat.